# Efficient SELECT from table of boolean changes

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to figure out an efficient query for a project I'm working on.

We're recording a switch state into a table, each time it changes, a row is added with the new value (0 or 1).

Here's a *simplified* structure of the table:

```
 day | hour | state 
-----+------+-------
  10 |    1 |     1  # day 10
  10 |    6 |     0 
  10 |   21 |     1 

  11 |    3 |     0  # day 11
  11 |    6 |     1

  13 |   13 |     0  # day 13
....
```

Now we need to make a daily overview, something like this:

```
Day 11 : Switch was on during 0-3, 6-24
```

`SELECT * FROM log WHERE day = 11` will give us only [3,0] and [6,1]. From those we can guess that it started ON and ended ON, but how about day 12?

`SELECT * FROM log WHERE day = 12` gives nothing, obviously - there's no clue to guess from.

What is an efficient and reliable way to get the starting and ending state for a given day? Something like **"Select one entry before day 12 and one after day 12"**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    day,
    hour,
    state
FROM
    log
WHERE
    day*100+hour 
    BETWEEN
        (SELECT max(day*100+hour) FROM log WHERE day < 12) 
    AND
        (SELECT min(day*100+hour) FROM log WHERE day > 12)
```

Will give you everything between (including) the last entry before day 12 and the first entry after day 12.
The second part might be unnecessary if you don't need to know when the state changed, and it's enough to know the state didn't change until at least midnight of the selected day.